# Boost unit testing with main

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

Consider the following code:

```
void free_test_function() {
    BOOST_CHECK(1 == 2);
    BOOST_CHECK(1 == 3);
}

boost::unit_test::test_suite* init_unit_test_suite(int, char*[]) {
    boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().p_name.value = "Unit test example 02";

    // register the test case in test tree and specify number of expected failures so
    // this example will pass at runtime. We expect 2 errors: one from failed check and 
    // one from memory acces violation
    boost::unit_test::framework::master_test_suite().add(BOOST_TEST_CASE(&free_test_function), 2);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    init_unit_test_suite(What?, What?);
}
```

Unit-tests in the following code won't be executed :(

Can I run unit-test with my own main function? How can I do it?

I heared about `BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN` macros, but I don't have any additional information about it.

Please, help me.

P.S. I **REALLY** want to implement it with my **OWN** `main()` function

Comment: why not read the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/boost/test/impl/unit_test_main.ipp) of boost?